# Empty item displaying from nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Rails and am building a todo app.

For some reason an empty `Item` instance is displaying within all lists by default. `Item.count` is returning 0, but `<%= render @list.items %>` always has one "instance" of _item.html.erb.

I have `@list` assigned to `List.find(params[:id])` in the list controller's show method and am calling `<%= render @list.items %>` in its show view.

I have this link in _item.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Delete", [item.list, item],
    method: :delete,
    data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
%>
```

and it will display the delete link, but link to `lists/*/items` (as opposed to `list/*/items/*`) in the empty item, which gives a routing error. The link works fine in actual items though.

Controllers:

lists_controller.rb:

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_list, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @lists = policy_scope(List).where(author: current_user)
  end

  def show
    @item = @list.items.build
  end

  def new
    @list = List.new
    authorize @list
  end

  def create
    @list = List.new(list_params)
    @list.author = current_user
    authorize @list

    if @list.save
      flash[:notice] = "Your list was created."
      redirect_to @list
    else
      flash[:error] = "Your list was not created."
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @list.update(list_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Your list was updated."
      redirect_to @list
    else
      flash[:error] = "Your list was not updated."
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if @list.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Your list was deleted."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Your list was not deleted."
      redirect_to @list
    end
  end

  private

  def list_params
    params.require(:list).permit(:title, :description, :author_id)
  end

  def set_list
      @list = List.find(params[:id])
      authorize @list
  end
end
```

items_controller.rb:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_list

  def create
    @item = @list.items.create(item_params)
    authorize @item

    if @item.save
      flash[:notice] = "Your item was added."
      redirect_to @list
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Your item was not added."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @item = @list.items.find(params[:id])
    authorize @item

    if @item.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Your item was deleted."
      redirect_to @list
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Your item was not deleted."
    end
  end

  private

  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:name, :list_id)
  end

  def set_list
    @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
  end
end
```

Models:

list.rb:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true

  belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"

  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
end
```

item.rb:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true

  belongs_to :list
end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "lists#index"

  resources :lists do
    resources :items
  end

  devise_for :users
end
```

Reference migration:

```
class AddListsToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :items, :list, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@item = @list.items.build` is your problem.

The issue is that *building* a nested item will always yield an "empty" item, especially if it's nested.

Whilst you *can* use the code in the `new` action with impunity, using in `show` will basically just create a blank object that you have to contend with.

--

If you want to create a `new` `item` object when viewing your `@list`, you'll be better building / invoking on the fly (as you're doing already):

```
<%= form_for [@list, @list.items.new] ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by the way I passed the instance variable to the form.

This line in `ListsController` is building a new item on each page refresh.

```
def show
   @item = @list.items.build
end
```

I removed that assignment, as well as its passing to the form.

`<%= render "items/form", list: @list, item: @item %>` becomes `<%= render "items/form", list: @list %>`

`simple_form_for([list, item]` becomes `simple_form_for([@list, @list.items.build]`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<%= render 'item' %>
```

and on your **_item.html.erb** (which is rendered), use the following code:

```
<%= @list.items %>
```

Comment: That puts this inside the `ul` element: `#<Item::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fc6a8359618>`. Assuming you mean for me to place _item.html.erb in views/lists.

Comment: Yup, you need to put the rendered template to you view folder where you called it.

Comment: I did that and that string was rendered on the page. The hexadecimal part changes on each refresh though.